# ASP.NET MVC - encrypted message not complete when sent on client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encryption, base64

I'm having trouble in sending the encrypted string on client side. I have an app that returns an encrypted data on client's side using Base64 encoded string. On my server and local the encrypted data is returning complete as expected. but when client is trying to open the application. It returns an incomplete encoded string. How can I make it send the complete encrypted string on client?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. I thought that the encrypted string gotten short but I figured that the data being encrypted is null.